# need to find out the source of angularjs factory values modifier

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

In my angularjs application, I am using factory to store the values and share them across the controllers. But I am getting into a peculiar problem.

The following is my factory :

```
    factory.quoteLinks = {allLinks : [], allLeftLinks :[],  curSection : "-1", insType: "-1", test:"-1"};

    factory.setQuoteLinks = function(qlinks, qleftLinks, qsubLink, qinsuranceType, testVal) {
            factory.quoteLinks = { allLinks : qlinks, allLeftLinks : qleftLinks, curSection: qsubLink, insType: qinsuranceType, test:testVal};
        };

    factory.getQuoteLinks = function() {
            return factory.quoteLinks;
        };
```

As far as I Know, the values will be stored in `factory.quoteLinks`, only when I call `factory.setQuoteLinks`. So whenever I explicitly make call to `factory.setQuoteLinks`, the values are correctly getting stored. After a while debugging remaining part of the code, during debugging, I noticed even though I am not calling `factory.setQuoteLinks`, the values of `allLinks` in `factory.quoteLinks` is getting modified to some other values and I am not able to figure out from where this is getting modified even though I am not calling `factory.setQuoteLinks` to modify the `allLinks` at that particular point. Is there any possibility for me to track from where this value in the factory is getting modified, I mean the cause for this modification? I left with no clue how to figure it out?

Comment: If the consumer/s of `factory.getQuoteLinks()` is/are modifying the collection those changes are made on the objects referenced by `factory.quoteLinks`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ax `Max Sorin` said you're probably modifying it outside of here because you're passing back the reference to it in `factory.getQuoteLinks`. If you need this changed use an angular copy:

```
factory.getQuoteLinks = function() {
        return angular.copy(factory.quoteLinks);
};
```

This will return a copied quoteLinks.